# How to provide my Android application into my website to download by users

Tags: android, android-ndk, google-play

I have developed a Android application. I would like to keep it in my website www.abc.example.com. I have permission for server access.

I would like to see my application as like we download softwares from the sites in the net directly. so that, all users will download my application which is very useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just upload your .apk file into web server and provide a link to upload. User can click this link and directly download from the server. But there is one issue for privacy, the .apk file can transfer to several device through Bluetooth etc.

And if the user cannot enable the settings for Unknown source installation from the setting will not allow this .apk file to install. Better create an account in Google Play and upload it.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to do anything else other than uploading APK file to server and provide link to that APK location.

On user side, user has to tick **Unknown sources (Allow installation of non-market apps)** inside Settings screen.

Comment: You might need to set the `Content-Type` (to `application/vnd.android.package-archive`) appropriately so that the browser, etc. will recognize it as an APK and give you the option to install.